# function that makes all combinations of permutations in r

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, permutation, combinatorics

I have vector of numbers

```
n_vector = c(0,1)
```

and I have k number. I need to make dataframe of all combinations of permutations.For k=3 it should be:

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
1 0 0
0 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

for k =4 the result should be:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0
1 0 0 0
0 0 1 1
0 1 0 1
1 0 0 1
0 1 1 0
1 0 1 0
1 1 0 0
1 1 1 0
1 1 0 1
1 0 1 1
0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
```

Is there any standart library of function that can make such dataframe?

Answer (score 3):

You can combine `replicate` and `expand.grid` to make such a function

```
fun <- function(x) {
   do.call("expand.grid", replicate(x, 0:1, simplify = FALSE))
}
fun(3)
fun(4)
```

Or another alternative using some bitwise logic:

```
fun <- function(x) {
  outer(0:(2^x-1), 2^(0:(x-1)), function(a, b) as.numeric(bitwAnd(a, b)>0))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's what `RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral` is designed for. Extremely fast, since implemented in C++.

```
library(RcppAlgos)
permuteGeneral(c(0, 1), 3, repetition=TRUE)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    1
# [3,]    0    1    0
# [4,]    0    1    1
# [5,]    1    0    0
# [6,]    1    0    1
# [7,]    1    1    0
# [8,]    1    1    1
permuteGeneral(c(0, 1), 4, repetition=TRUE)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#  [1,]    0    0    0    0
#  [2,]    0    0    0    1
#  [3,]    0    0    1    0
#  [4,]    0    0    1    1
#  [5,]    0    1    0    0
#  [6,]    0    1    0    1
#  [7,]    0    1    1    0
#  [8,]    0    1    1    1
#  [9,]    1    0    0    0
# [10,]    1    0    0    1
# [11,]    1    0    1    0
# [12,]    1    0    1    1
# [13,]    1    1    0    0
# [14,]    1    1    0    1
# [15,]    1    1    1    0
# [16,]    1    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#install if necessary
install.packages('gtools')
#load library
library(gtools)
#urn with 3 balls
x <- c('red', 'blue', 'black')
#pick 2 balls from the urn with replacement
#get all permutations
permutations(n=3,r=2,v=x,repeats.allowed=T)
#      [,1]    [,2]   
# [1,] "black" "black"
# [2,] "black" "blue" 
# [3,] "black" "red"  
# [4,] "blue"  "black"
# [5,] "blue"  "blue" 
# [6,] "blue"  "red"  
# [7,] "red"   "black"
# [8,] "red"   "blue" 
# [9,] "red"   "red"
#number of permutations
nrow(permutations(n=3,r=2,v=x,repeats.allowed=T))
#[1] 9
```